# Upgrade Expo react-native-svg dependency version

Tags: expo, react-native-svg

My Expo project requires the latest version of `react-native-svg` library to render my SVGs correctly. Currently it's version 9.3.5

From `package-json.lock`, I see that my current Expo SDK 32 has version 8.0.10 listed.

```
"dependencies": {
        "react-native-svg": {
          "version": "8.0.10",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-svg/-/react-native-svg-8.0.10.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-gsG5GUdvlox67+ohLnq3tZSqiYBmz4M5lKKeUfnJZ8EPrMMS5ZgaVj7Zcccee1VvINS5xQaoenUJdha/GEo34w==",
          "requires": {
            "color": "^2.0.1",
            "lodash": "^4.16.6",
            "pegjs": "^0.10.0"
          }
        }
      }
```

I have tried just installing latest react-native-svg alongside Expo by using

```
npm install react-native-svg@9.3.5
```

However, when running the app I get an error:

```
Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect
```

So how can I force Expo to use the latest version? I don't see any `react-native-svg` dependencies anywhere and changing the `package-lock.json` directly doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I have a confustion. I am using expo 33 and i need to use Svg. But since react-native-svg library needs to be linked, how's that gonna work in expo?

Comment: Expo SDK 33 already includes react-native-svg as a dependency "react-native-svg": "~9.4.0", specifically. You can just use SVG without linking any additional libraries by using the API. Docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to my question is: you can't. At least not without some ugly hacks that are more trouble than they're worth.
The good news is that SDK 33 now comes with "react-native-svg": "~9.4.0" as a dependency and this is almost the latest version as of this writing.